# Artifactory: Allow Group to Create Private Repositories for that Group

Tags: artifactory

In Artifactory, is there currently a way to allow members of an ldap group (for example, "my_team_admins") to create and manage repositories for that group?

I'm looking for a solution that is similar to how GitHub has organization level permissions which allow a subset of admins to manage repositories in that organization.

The best solution would be one that is either built in or that can be accomplished with an already available plugin, and that would be supported by an existing contract with jFrog.

Creating my own plugin (or other type of application) is not an option for me at this time.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently a roadmap item.
What you can do now is to set a group, either an LDAP group or internal group as Admins and that will grant them the permissions of an Admin.

Comment: Are you able to restrict those admins to certain repositories, so they don’t modify or have access to everything?

Comment: Oh, and also .. do you have a link to the roadmap to verify your post? I think with that I could consider the question answered.

Comment: @Pytry the answer for both of your questions is no. The Admin in Artifactory has full access to all. there is an open Jira for it: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-7253. 
The Jira site for JFrog is public and it is what driven JFrog roadmap, meaning that if a specific request has a lot of voters it is most likely to be added to the roadmap, however, the roadmap itself is internal.